# Sqoop import job error org.kitesdk.data.ValidationException for Oracle

Tags: oracle, hadoop, ojdbc, sqoop

Sqoop import job for Oracle 11g fails with error

> ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop:
>   org.kitesdk.data.ValidationException: Dataset name
>   81fdfb8245ab4898a719d4dda39e23f9_C46010.HISTCONTACT is not
>   alphanumeric (plus '_')

here's the complete command:

```
$ sqoop job --create ingest_amsp_histcontact -- import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:<PORT>/<SID>" --username "c46010" -P --table C46010.HISTCONTACT --check-column ITEM_SEQ --target-dir /tmp/junk/amsp.histcontact -as-parquetfile -m 1 --incremental append

$ sqoop job --exec ingest_amsp_histcontact
```

it's an incremental import with parquet format. Surprisingly, it works pretty well if I use another format like --as-textfile.

This is similar issue with [Sqoop job fails with KiteSDK validation error for Oracle import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276816/sqoop-job-fails-with-kitesdk-validation-error-for-oracle-import)

But I've used ojdbc6 and switched to ojdbc7 doesn't work as well.

Sqoop version: 1.4.7

Oracle version: 11g

Thanks,
Yusata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround, omitting "." character in --table parameter works for me, so instead of `--table <schema>.<table_name>`, I use `--table <table_name>`. But this doesn't work if you import a table from another schema in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is kind of late but I faced the same problem and I solved it by omitting parquet file option.

Try running the job without

```
-as-parquetfile
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "." in --target-dir option. Workaround here: Change target dir to "/tmp/junk/amsp_histcontact". When sqoop job finishes, rename the hdfs target dir to "/tmp/junk/amsp.histcontact"